# Mongoose after upgrade to 4.5.9 with mongo 3.2.0 giving unhandled error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

To gain performance that mongo 3.2 is providing we have upgraded to mongo 3.2 from 3.0 with mongoose version upgraded from 3.8.8 to 4.5.9. But we are getting following errors and not able to find out the reason for it.

```
events.js:141
 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
 ^

TypeError: callback.apply is not a function
at Query.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/urbanclap/service-market/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3327:16)
at /home/ubuntu/urbanclap/service-market/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:259:21
at /home/ubuntu/urbanclap/service-market/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:127:16
at doNTCallback0 (node.js:408:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:337:13)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
error: Script restart attempt #11
Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
```

From Mongoose code I got to know that it is emitting error with following code.

```
Model.$wrapCallback = function(callback) {
var _this = this;
return function() {
  try {
    callback.apply(null, arguments);
  } catch (error) {
    _this.emit('error', error);
  }
};
};
```

Comment: can you post some of your code? May be the part where it is showing error in `events.js`

Comment: Added comment above, this mongoose code is giving error. May be some issue but whatever it is emitting we are catching in promise outside, but still shows unhandled error.

Comment: You should try and trace back which of your own code is triggering this error. It looks like Mongoose is expecting a callback to be passed to some function or other, and it's not getting one. From the location the error is thrown, I would suspect a [`post` hook](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html).

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of the mongoose latest version, we have to explicitly add the promises.

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://10.7.0.3:27107/data/db');
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

Comment: We have already done that, but still this error is coming up.

Comment: change the port num on which server is running. it might be helpful.

Comment: How port change will help ? Do u mean node port or mongodb port ?

Comment: No help, but how would it help in first place ?

Comment: Once i have faced the same issue and i worked for me. Node JS and one more application is running on the same port. When i have changed the port number it worked for me...!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121885/discussion-between-user1776860-and-vora-ankit).